# Round to the nearest factor of N

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

Given a number, `x` (like 13), and a factor `N` (like 2), how can I compute the values 8 and 16 below?

```
8 <= 13 < 16
```

In other words, how can I compute the two ends of the equality here:

```
N^? <= x < N^(? + 1)
```

Comment: Is N int or float ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the floored n<sup>th</sup> logarithm of the number and use it as value for getting the power of `f` and `f` plus one.

```js
function getInterval(x, n) {
    var f = Math.floor(Math.log(x) / Math.log(n));
    return [Math.pow(n, f), Math.pow(n, f + 1)];
}

console.log(getInterval(3, 2).join(' '));
console.log(getInterval(23, 7).join(' '));
console.log(getInterval(13, 2).join(' '));
```

Comment: what is not working with it? what result do you expect?

Comment: I would expect 8 and 16

Comment: excellent. Thank you and my apologies for the complete lack of clarity initially

Answer (score 1):

Edit. Question sense was completely changed.

```
pwr = Math.floor(Math.log(x) / Math.log(n))
low = Math.pow(n, pwr)
high = Math.pow(n, pwr + 1)
```